# #include <header.h> error: Cannot open source file "header.h"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header, include

I'm trying to include the header of a class called Person (Person.h) into my implementation of Person (Person.cpp), but I keep getting an error saying:

"cannot open source file Person.h"

The .h file and .cpp file are in the same directory:
[image]

And these are my settings of the include directories:
[image]

Comment: add `$(ProjectDir)` to include directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use`#include "header.h"` instead of `#include <header.h>` to include project files. Read C++ Primer for more reference.